# How to authenticate with API Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I created a usage plan, associated it to the default stage and created an API key.

Then I created authorizer pointing to my Lambda function and set identity source to `header` and called it `key`.

I disabled authorization catching.

Then I went to my method request, I choose my authorizer and switched *API Key Required* to `true`.

I also added `key` header to *HTTP Request Headers*.

I deployed API, and after making a call with Postman I'm getting two different responses:

- Without `key` in headers: `{    "message": "Unauthorized"}`
- With `key` in headers: `{    "message": null}`

Whenever I post `key` in the header, I'm getting such response no matter what the content of the `key` is. Obliviously I'm using a previously generated API key.

What I'm missing here?

Comment: please post the code of your authorizer function

Comment: @varnit Looks like authorizer function is the thing that I'm missing. Damn, I thought that AWS is taking care of it.. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS supports two types of authentication mechanism for api gateway

1. Using cognito user pools
2. using custom authorizer

you have to use one of them or it will return null for a sample authorizer function you can refer to an example in github repository

[Custom Authorizer Api Gateway](https://github.com/varnitgoyal95/IT-Academy-/tree/master/lambda/It-Academy-Lambda/authenticator)

Comment: I'm trying to make basic authorization for my microservice (which is just a one, simple lambda function), so only a few people that I would create API keys for would be able to invoke it. I'm not trying to make SaaS service for millions of users, and with this case, everything becomes very confusing. What would be the right thing to do in this case?

Comment: the thing is your question is very broad and you have to share a lot of details until we can reach to some conclusion, if you use any service on aws its infinitely scalable by default because that is what cloud computing is made for and api gateway supports both authorization and throttling so, as far as i can understand your question i think api gateway authorization is a good fit but the answer is very optionated and someone might have different preference

Comment: Okay, I realized what my issue was. I wanted simply to authorize with an API key, so authorizer normally would not be necessary at all. The API key can be simply passed in the HTTP request headers. However, my case is little more complicated, and because of that the only way to pass API key for me is the query in URL, but that's a completely different story, for another question maybe. Thanks for taking your time to reply!